# How do I validate dynamic field on Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and just in the learning process. I am trying to work on some minor project which I am having a issue with.
I add the rows dynamically. And when I validate it validates all the previous indexes of this input which has data and are in proper format along with the current empty field. My question here is how do I validate the row based on index if the row is added dynamically.

HTML Code:
    The below code has three input fields that are required and click of the button, the adding of rows and removing of rows.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" ng-submit="createReferralCateogry()">
           <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="contactPerson in referral.contactPersons track by $index">
                    <div class="contactPerson">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <label for="contactperson ">Contact Person Name:</label>
                            <input type="text " class="form-control   " ng-model="referral.contactPersons[$index].personName " name="ConPersonName[$index]" placeholder="Contact Person" required>
                            <div class="validationmsg " ng-messages="addReferralForm.ConPersonName[$index].$error " ng-if="addReferralForm.ConPersonName[$index].$touched " role="alert ">
                                <div ng-message="required ">Please Enter Contact Person's Name</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <label for="contactperson ">Contact Person Designation:</label>
                            <input type="text " class="form-control   " ng-model="referral.contactPersons[$index].designation " name="ConPersonDesig[$index]" placeholder="Designation " required>
                            <div class="validationmsg " ng-messages="addReferralForm.ConPersonDesig[$index].$error " ng-if="addReferralForm.ConPersonDesig[$index].$touched " role="alert ">
                                <div ng-message="required ">Please Enter Contact Person's Designation</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <label for="contactperson]">Contact Person Mobile Number:</label>
                            <input type="number " class="form-control   " ng-model="referral.contactPersons[$index].mobileNumber" ng-minlength="10 " ng-maxlength="12 " name="ConPersonPH[$index]" placeholder="Mobile Number " required>
                            <div class="validationmsg " ng-messages="addReferralForm.ConPersonPH[$index].$error " ng-if="addReferralForm.ConPersonPH[$index].$touched " role="alert ">
                                <div ng-message="required ">Please Enter Contact Person's Mobile Number</div>
                                <div ng-message="minlength ">Your Mobile Number is too short</div>
                                <div ng-message="maxlength ">Your Mobile Number is too long</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 mtop25">
                            <label class="control-label"></label>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph_size addContactPerson " ng-class="$index==0? 'btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus': 'btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-minus' " aria-hidden="true " ng-click="addRemoveContactPerson($index) "></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </form>
```

JS: 
The javascript code to add and remove the contactperson is done here.

```
$scope.addRemoveContactPerson = function(index) {
        if (index == 0) $scope.referral.contactPersons.push({
            personName: "",
            designation: "",
            mobileNumber: ""
        })
        else {
            $scope.referral.contactPersons.pop();
        }
    };
```

Comment: use `$scope.referral.contactPersons.unshift` instead of `push`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use {{}} interpolation when using $index for naming dynamic control Try this it works for me:

```
 <input type="text " class="form-control" ng-model="referral.contactPersons[$index].personName " name="{{'ConPersonName_'+$index}}" placeholder="Contact Person" required>
                        <div class="validationmsg " ng-messages="addReferralForm['ConPersonName_'+$index].$error " ng-if="addReferralForm['ConPersonName_'+$index].$touched " role="alert ">
                            <div ng-message="required ">Please Enter Contact Person's Name</div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: when i define ng-messages="addReferralForm.['ConPersonName'+$index].error", It says that I cannot use an array. So how do I resolve this. Is there a better way @Jenny

Comment: you can do it by removing (.) so its will be  ng-messages="addReferralForm['ConPersonName'+$index].error"‌​ see in my answer

Comment: its pleasure to help accept as answer for helping other.

Comment: Since I am still a newbie I didnt know that it would work without a (.) notation!

Comment: But the basic synatax would be formName.inputname . So i thought the (.) notation is mandatroy @Jenny

Comment: formNaMe.ControlName is used for already created input. but in dynamic we dnt knw name of control thats y we use this!